# "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized." Getting this issue while authenticate salesforce using c#

Tags: api, c#

Getting Following issue while authenticate salesforce using C#:

> The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

My code:

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://ap8.salesforce.com/services/data/v37.0/sobjects/Account");
httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/Json";
httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer 6Cel800D0o0000018EWH8880o0000019quiPSXZfGP3CizqogLL0BhkN4ZhMPuqN0EuObUlmQPRszCqFkkQlhQ09U8r8XXXXXXXXX");
var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
Console.WriteLine("Response" + httpResponse);
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Please help me out from this?

Comment: Please use *relevant tags*. It's not clear how this question relates to `salesforce1-app`, `salesforcedx`, or `salesforce-id`, which is why I originally removed the first one from the question.

Comment: Whats the instance url you get from login call

Comment: Hi. This appears very similar to the sample sample code that Salesforce provides. https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Consuming_Force.com_SOAP_and_REST_Web_Services_from_.NET_Applications#Querying_and_Creating_Objects_Via_REST_API 
You might want to try that code in case there are some slight differences. Otherwise, verify that your access token and server URL are valid.

Answer (score -1):

You have your password + token in the wrong order. Use it as the following (without blank spaces and <>.):

```
<password><token>
```